# Spinor-helicity like formalism for scalar fields coupled to an $SU(2)$ gauge field?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, spinors, helicity

In QCD, even the cross sections of the simplest processes have lots of terms, but we can of course use the spinor helicity formalism to massively simplify the expression.

My question - say we have a scalar field coupled to an $SU(2)$ gauge field instead of the usual spinor field, then would we still have the spinor-helicity formalism? Or will it be replaced by some other technology that simplifies the processes?

My scalar $\vec{\phi} = (\phi_1, \cdots, \phi_3)$ transforms as $\phi_i \rightarrow U_{ij} \phi_j$ with $U_{ij} = \delta_{ij} - \theta^a T^a_{jk}$ being an infinitesmal transformation, and $T^a$ are the 3x3 Rotation matrices. I want my lagrangian to be simply $$(D_\mu \phi)^2 + tr(F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu})$$ where $D_\mu = \partial_\mu - ig A_\mu^a T^a$ is the covariant derivative and $F^{\mu \nu}$ is the field strength.

We will then get multiple feynmann diagrams but exactly like QCD, since color is involved, even the simplest processes will have far too many terms. I know that I can reduce it a bit by observing the gauge field is massless. I can also use the Ward identity to reduce the dof further, but is there a way to apply the spinor helicity formalism in this field theory? Or something similar?

Srednicki first derives the formalism due to the presence of spinors in QED/QCD (in chapter 50/60) but then uses it in chapter 81 to show that certain 3-gluon vertices also will be 0 using the formalism:

[image]

This motivates me to ask: can I still use the spinor-helicity formalism when there were no spinors in the theory in the first place? Using spinor-helicity formalism, will I be able to say (some statement that is of the form) "this 3 gluon vertex is 0 even in the scalar QCD theory"? If not, what else may I use?